# Create React Component that looks similar to existing Component

Tags: reactjs

I have a Card component. I want to create a Component that is similar in appearance with small differences.
it will likely have additional/ different functionality (event handlers etc)

What is the best way to architect this? Do i just create a new component or are there better strategies?

Thanks

Comment: You can create generic component which will accept these eventHandlers as props. Now, you can use these generic components from any where and pass your own implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are very minor differences, pass a prop into the Card Component, and have an `if` statement in there that results in different functionality.

However, if the functionality is different (different state, events etc), then duplicating the component and changing it can often be the cleaner solution.

As ever with deciding on architecture, both are valid, and it really depends on how large the differences are, and how (in the future) each of the components are likely to change.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the component itself as a blueprint (I hesitate using "class" here because JavaScript). When you mount the component inside your render function, or in the case of functional components your returned component, you are "instantiating" that blueprint/class.

So for your example, you have a `<Card onPress={someEventHandler} style={somestyle}/>`.

You want another `<Card />` component with different style and handler? Just instantiate it again:

`<Card onPress={someOtherEventHandler} style={someOtherStyle} />`

Maybe you want another `<Card />` component with same style, but different handler? Easy:

`<Card onPress={someOtherEventHandler} style={someStyle} />`

Similar to instantiating objects in standard OOP, there is no right or wrong answer to this. If you need a card for each element in an array, use a map:

`{someArrayOfCards.map(card => <Card onPress={someEventHandler} style={someStyle}/>)}`

Hope that answers your question.

EDIT: Another important thing to understand is that each component represents a node on the VDOM/DOM. The reason it actually doesn't matter which architecture is used to instantiate each component is because you're creating a separate node regardless.